# Unable to Upload file in Symfony get .tmp format in SQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony

First on is Form and second one is form details i mark box which error i am facing:

[image]

Unable to upload file in Symfony and my database accept "C:\xampp\tmp\php14FE.tmp" file. Am I using right method?

```
**HomeController.php**


<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use MyBundle\Entity\school;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use MyBundle\Models\Login;
//use MyBundle\Entity\Article;
use MyBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;





class HomeController extends Controller
{


     /**
     * @Route("/", name="form")
     */

    public function formAction(Request $request)
    {

    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $user = new school();


        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)


            ->add('userName', TextType::class)
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add('emailId', EmailType::class)
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class) 
            ->add('uploadfile', FileType::class)


            //->add('form', 'submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))

            ->getForm();


            $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
     // Get Data

        $un = $form['userName']->getData();
        $fn = $form['firstName']->getData();
        $ln = $form['lastName']->getData();
        $email = $form['emailId']->getData();
        $pass = $form['password']->getData();
        $fil = $form['uploadfile']->getData();




    $user->setUserName($un);
    $user->setFirstName($fn);
    $user->setLastName($ln);
    $user->setEmailId($email);
    $user->setPassword($pass);
    $user->setUploadFile($fil);



    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 


    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();


         /* $response = new JsonResponse(array('status' => 'success', 'message' =>'Data has been Inserted successfully'));
         return $response;   
         */ 
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('view_name'));
    }


        return $this->render('MyBundle:mine:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));


    }


     /**
     * @Route("/view", name="view_name")
     */

    public function viewAction(Request $request)
    {

     $userdata = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:school')
    ->findAll();    

    return $this->render('MyBundle:mine:view.html.twig', array('view' => $userdata));


    //return $userdata;

    }
```

This is my form.html.twig file, I used form_widget method.

```
**form.html.twig**

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1 class="head">STUDENT REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form_person_edit'}}) }}


{{ form_widget(form) }}
<!--{{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-group'} }) }}-->


<button type="submit" id="create" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>


{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheets %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/style.css') }}" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/jquery-ui.css') }}" >
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/demo.js') }}"></script>

        <script>
        var formURL="{{path('form')}}";
        var viewURL="{{path('view_name')}}";

        </script>


        {% endblock %}
```

This my view.html.twig file it's show me "C:\xampp\tmp\php14FE.tmp" in but i gave .jpg format suggest me much better method for upload file in symfony. i have seen many method of upload but i don't know why my database taking .temp file.

```
    **view.html.twig**

{% block stylesheets %}


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap.css') }}" >

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap-grid.css') }}" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}" >

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" >

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css') }}" >


        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/demo.js') }}"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>



        {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container" >

<h2>STUDENT INFORMATION FORM</h2>

<table  id="table_view" border=""> 



<thead>
<tr>
    <th >USER NAME</th>
    <th >FIRST NAME</th>
    <th >LAST NAME</th>
    <th >EMAIL ID</th>
    <th >PASSWORD</th>
    <th >UPLOADED FILE</th>
    <th >EDIT</th>
    <th >DELETE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for key in view %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{  key.UserName }}</td>
    <td>{{  key.FirstName }}</td>
    <td>{{  key.LastName }}</td>
    <td>{{  key.EmailId }}</td>
    <td>{{  key.Password }}</td>
    <td>{{  key.UploadFile }}</td>

    <td><span class="link"><a href="/my_project/web/app_dev.php/edit/{{ key.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Edit</a><span></td>
    <td><span class="link"><a href="/my_project/web/app_dev.php/delete/{{ key.id }}" class="deleteUser btn btn-danger btn-md">Delete</a><span></td>
</tr>

<!--<span class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>-->


{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#table_view').DataTable();
              });
        </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and try to describe the error you are receiving. Is it just not working or is an error message available?

Comment: sir iam not getting any error my program is not working, iam getting .temp file in the place of my file which i have uploaded.